# Show that $~f~$ is uniformly continuous on all of $~\mathbb R~$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, uniform-continuity

Suppose $~f: \mathbb R\to \mathbb R~$ is a function that for every $~x,~y~$ in $~\mathbb R~$, $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)~$ and $~f~$ is continuous at $~0~$. Show that $~f~$ is uniformly continuous on all of $~\mathbb R~$.

I tried proving that for every epsilon > 0, there exists delta > 0 such that |x-x0| < delta and |f(x)-f(x0)| < epsilon but I did not know really what to do with the given information.

Comment: What have you tried?  Why is this question relevant to you?

Comment: I tried proving that for every epsilon > 0, there exists delta > 0 such that |x-x0| < delta and |f(x)-f(x0)| < epsilon  but I did not know really what to do with the given information

Comment: @Alex : It is much better to write your attempts below your question/problem and not in a comment. That way you prevent down votes from people who permanently suspect that you may just want to get your homework solved. Some of them are even so aggressive that they down vote correct answers.

Comment: Thanks for the advice just added it to my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the following

- $f(0) = f(0+0) = 2f(0) \Rightarrow f(0) = 0$
- $\lim_{h\to 0}f(h) = f(0) = 0 \Rightarrow \forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \delta >0: |h|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(h)| < \epsilon$

Now, for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$ you have:
$$|f(x+h)-f(x)| \stackrel{f(x+h) = f(x) + f(h)}{=} |f(h)| < \epsilon \mbox{ for } |h| < \delta$$

Since $\epsilon$ is independent of $x$, this is uniform continuity.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you $\it{could}$ attempt to "solve: for $f$:

Given $f(x+y) = f(x)+f(y)$ and $f$ continuous at $0$, you can then try to see which known functions satisfy the given equation. Such an equation is called a functional equation.

To find out what $f$ is at $0$, we do as in the answer given by trancelocation and get that:

$f(0)=f(0+0)=2f(0) \implies f(0)=0$

Next, we solve for $f$. A good educated guess will suggest that $f(x)=cx$, i.e. a linear equation. This is indeed correct.

Finally, you can argue (similar as done in trancelocation's answer) that $f(x)=cx$ is uniformly continuous and you are done.

For more on functional equations, see:

https://brilliant.org/wiki/functional-equations/
https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Cauchy_Functional_Equation

Hopefully this is interesting and adds a new perspective :)

(Note: I used the assumption that $f$ is continuous at $0$ to get the function as $f(x)=cx$. Without this assumption, there can also be other functions which are (heavily) discontinuous.)